# How to save video while predicting with super-gradient library model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, yolo, yolov8

I have a code

```
from super_gradients.training import models
from super_gradients.common.object_names import Models

yolo_x_n = models.get(Models.YOLOX_N, pretrained_weights="coco")
yolo_x_n.to("cpu")
yolo_x_n.predict_webcam()
```

How can I save the output of the video for to the current directory with name "output_yolo.avi"?
for example to use it further for presentation

Comment: you need to look into the function `predict_webcam` and add code to write the frames to a file.